# Use PowerShell to install Windows Updates in vSphere

Tags: powershell, automation, vsphere

I have a cluster of vSphere windows clients approximately 100 that I want to remotely automate windows updates on weekly. I have listed all the windows machine out in text file on my desktop. I have run the PSWindowsUpdate module on my local windows10 machine with command:
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate and then executed the below script successful for my local machine to run windows updates.

```
#Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
#Remove-Item -Path C:\Scripts\status.tx
#Start-Transcript -Path C:\Scripts\status.txt
#$Updates = "Critical Updates", "Security Updates"
#Get-WUInstall -AcceptALL- Verbose -IgnoreReboot -Category $Updates
#Write-Host "Done"
#Stop-Transcript
#Start-Sleep -s 120
#Restart-Computer -Force -Confirm:$false
```

-- after pc restarts run as PS As Administrator
#Get-WindowsUpdate

However, I am not a expert at PowerShell so, I do not know what to additionally script to accomplish the task of remotely updating 100 or so windows clients in vSphere.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: VMware powershell commandlets do not interact directly with the guest OS on VMs. You will need to write the Powershell script to update a remote computer (regardless of if its a VM or a normal desktop) and then use your list of names to deploy the updates using that script.

Comment: Thank-You Scepticalist:                                                                                               
 I just installed RSAT Tools.                                                                                           #Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "RSAT*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the invoke-command. You can create a server list from a DC:

```
$Servers = Get-ADObject -Filter * -Properties Name,OperatingSystem | Where-Object OperatingSystem -like '*Server*'
```

And use this list with a loop like this

```
ForEach($_ in $Servers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-WUInstall -AcceptALL- Verbose -IgnoreReboot -Category $Updates } -ComputerName $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: [PowerShell: Retrieve List of Domain-Computers by Operating System]

#Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' `
-Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address |
Sort-Object -Property Operatingsystem |
Select-Object -Property Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address

Comment: Thank You for the suggestions. --                                                                                             #wmic qfe list [shows recent updated list] #Get-WUaHistory | Format-Table [Retrieves all Windows updates, formatted as a table]

Comment: Exported list of all installed Hotfixes on all Domain Computers. Disadvantage of the following command is you do not know whether the computers are turned on or not. If you want to know which computers are not reachable remove the parameter "ErrorAction SilentlyContinue."  -----------  #Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name {Get-HotFix} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object PSComputername, HotfixID, InstalledOn | Out-GridView  ------------